# I am facing this error: Activity cannot override getParam()

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

This is in Java and not in Kotlin.

I tried making it publib and I searched everywhere but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your getParams() func to another name

Comment: i dont know what should i use here

Comment: where you call your getParams() func @PriyanshJr.